# Why Dialog does not have a NavController [Missing]?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use the latest update of Nav Component in my application

where i can add dialog(`BottomSheetDialogFragment`) in my `nav graph`

```
nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha05"
```

Part of code from my `nav_graph`:

```
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
        android:name="com.andor.navigate.notepad.listing.fragment.SettingFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_setting">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingFragment_to_confirmationFragment"
            app:destination="@id/confirmationFragment" />
    </dialog>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/confirmationFragment"
        android:name="com.andor.navigate.notepad.ConfirmationFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_confirmation" />
```

In my Setting's Fragment i have a button(`logout_btn`) to trigger the action: `action_settingFragment_to_confirmationFragment`

code in `OnActivityCreated` of the Setting's fragment:

```
    logout_btn.setOnClickListener {
       Navigation.findNavController(view!!).navigate(R.id.action_settingFragment_to_confirmationFragment)
    }
```

When i Click on the button there is a runtime Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: View
>   androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{550ae09 V.E......
>   ........ 1,1-719,526} does not have a NavController set
>           at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
>           at com.andor.navigate.notepad.listing.fragment.SettingFragment$onActivityCreated$2.onClick(SettingFragment.kt:56)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
>           at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)

My aim is to open a dialog from another dialog, but for some reason my dialog is not having(missing) NavController.

I have already referred to the source [code](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/949238/2/navigation/integration-tests/testapp/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/testapp/LearnMoreDialogFragment.kt#23)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A `DialogFragment` operates in an entirely separate window which is not in the same view hierarchy as your `NavController`.

You should use `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)` (where `this` is your `DialogFragment`)) or the Kotlin extension `findNavController()` if you are using the `fragment-ktx` dependency which walks up the *fragment* hierarchy to find your NavController.

Comment: I tried using above and faced https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134089818
the application is crashing will post as a separate question.

Comment: in case of dialog to dialog action's there is no issue while in case of dialog to fragment action crash happen's